# Filtration to define a martingale for the difference of two Brownian motions

Tags: measure-theory, brownian-motion, martingales, filtrations

Suppose we want to find a filtration, say $(\mathcal{F}_t)$, to ensure that $Z_t := B_{8t}-6C_t$ is a martingale, where $B$ and $C$ are two independent Brownian motions.

For this, we want to ensure that each $Z_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t-$measurable. I am thinking that $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(B_{8s}, s \leq t) \cap \sigma(C_{s}, s \leq t)$ for all $t$ would do the trick, although I am not sure how I would confirm this. Moreover, I am not sure if scaling $C$ would have an impact here. I would appreciate any hints here if possible.

Comment: Why should the difference be measurable with respect to the intersection? I would rather try $\mathcal F_t=\sigma(\{B_{8s}:s\le t\}\cup\{C_s:s\le t\})$.

Comment: I see. Would the $6$ in front of the $C_t$ have an effect? If so, why?

Comment: The factor does not matter for measurability.